# How to generate data with a specific trend in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to test the Akaike criterion (it is a criterion that gives where do you get a significant change in a time series), but to do that I need to generate data that for example follow a sinusoidal trend, a linear trend with positive or negative slope, a constant trend, etc. So far I have done this but with random numbers, this is:

```
%Implementation of the Akaike method for Earth sciences.

N=100;
data=zeros(N,1);

for i=1:N
    data(i,1)=unifrnd(1,N);
end

%AIC=zeros(N-1,1);
data=rand(1,N);
for k=1:N
    %y=datasample(data,k);
    AIC(k,1)=k*log(var(data(1:k),1))+(N-k-1)*log(var(data(k+1:N),1));

end
AIC(1)=NaN;
%AIC(N-1)=[];AIC(N)=[];
%disp(AIC)
%plot(AIC)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(data,'Marker','.')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(AIC,'Marker','.')
```

So, How can I generate different data with different trend in MATLAB?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why don't you start off with those curves and add some noise to it?

Comment: How do you add noise? Can you elaborate please? :) Thanks

Comment: `rand`, `randn`, etc.

Comment: Right but I have already tested my program with random numbers :)

Comment: `Yn = f(X) + noise`

Comment: You mean something like Yn=sin(X)+rand , correct?

Comment: Yup.  `f(X)` is any general curve, like `sin`, `cos`, a line, etc.  Give it a go and see how it is.  If you're still confused, I can provide an answer.

Comment: Ok I agree, just give me sometime to check it and if I still confused I will accept you the answer please :)

Comment: Sorry but What would be X?

Comment: `X` is the set of independent values you want your function to take on... looking at your code, `X = 1 : N`.

Comment: A ok good then let me try it :) and I'll be back :)

Comment: @rayryeng I've got the sine and the line, but How do perform the constant graph? Thanks :)

Comment: `X = B*ones(1, N)` where `B` is your constant value.

Comment: I've added an answer for you. This should hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first start off with a known curve, then add some noise or random values so that the signal does follow a trend but it is noisy.  Given a set of independent values, use these to generate values for your sinusoidal curves, a line with a positive or negative slope and a constant value.

Something like this comes to mind:

```
X = 1 : N; % N is defined in your code
Y1 = sin(X) + rand(1, N); % Sinusoidal

slope1 = 2; intercept = 3;
Y2 = slope1*X + intercept + rand(1, N);  % Line with a positive slope

slope2 = -1; intercept2 = 0.5;
Y3 = slope2*X + intercept2 + rand(1, N); % Line with a negative slope

B = 2;
Y4 = B*ones(1, N) + rand(1, N); % Constant line
```

[`rand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) is a function in MATLAB that uniformly generates floating-point values between `[0,1]`.  `Y1, Y2, Y3` and `Y4` are the trends you desire where they follow the curve defined but they add a bit of random values so that you don't completely get the trend you want and the noise is designed to decrease how similarity those curves are to the curve you defined.  Increase the magnitude of the random values to decrease the similarity.